# Missing lock icon in System Preferences->Sharing on El Capitan

Tags: macos, system-settings

See attached image below. I have a few macs and on one of them, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to lock the Sharing tab under System Preferences. The lock is present and working on other panes that support locking. I also went to Security & Privacy advanced and could not find anything there. How do I re-enable the ability to lock this pane and does anyone know why or how it got that way? My other Macs don't have this problem.

Edit: I am including another screenshot from my other Mac to show that there is indeed a lock on that pane.

I am running OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 on a Macbook Pro Retina (late 2013)[image: Mac OS X System Preferences Pane]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no lock on this screen.  There is only a lock if the setting requires an `Administrator` (someone with the role of **Administrator**) to make the changes (i.e. **Security**).  If anyone can make the changes then there's no need for a lock.

Make sure you're logged-in with the role of **Administrator** to see the preferences that you can lock/unlock.

**EDIT: based on OP's new comments:**
  - Log in as a user with **Administrator** rights.
  - Open `System Preferences` and select `Security & Privacy`.
  - Click the lock icon and authenticate.
  - Click the `Advanced` button at the bottom and enable the `Require an Administrator...` in the popup window.
  - `OK` the change and then lock the S&P preference pane.

Now when you open the `Sharing` preference pane you will have your lock back.

Comment: There is a lock on that screen. See below from my other Mac.

https://imgur.com/PZA0BrA

Comment: There is only one account on that machine and it is the administrator account. I have no other accounts and guest is disabled.

Comment: I don't have the lock on my Mac and I'm the only user and administrator.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't want anyone to be able to make the change. Not even me unless I unlock the setting with a password just like other panes in Preferences. You say "anyone can make the changes then there's no need for a lock" but I don't want this. I want it like my other Mac where not anyone can make the change as I have locked it. Both machines only have 1 user and that user is the administrator. So why does one machine not have it? How come you and and fbara don't see this? There must be a setting somewhere.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: That's it!!!! Thanks. I would delete the first paragraph of the current answer and make the edit the answer. This is exactly what I wanted.